# How to disable bizarre new import re-write shortcut in VSCode 1.25

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've accidentally pressed a shortcut (not sure what) twice today since upgrading to 1.25. I can't fathom the point of it but it re-writes imports that it finds type definitions for in my WHOLE project:

[image]

Any idea what this shortcut is and how I can disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in 1.25 where it re-writes all the imports it finds which have typescript defs in the global TS module when you rename a file (even in projects not using TS)